# How do I center elements on a page using percentage widths?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a webpage with a horizontal parallax effect. I set my page width to 400% so that I could have 4 pages and thus it'll respond to different browser widths. However, how would I center elements within each page sections(i.e. how to center elements on sections 0-100%, 101-200%, etc.) I've tried setting a specified width and then using `margin: 0 auto`, but to no avail. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div id="transition-slide-container">   <!--begin transition-slide-container-->         
            <div id="transition-slide">
                <div class="slide" id="home">
                    <div id="inner-container">
                        <h1>home</h1>                       
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide" id="portfolio">
                    <div id="inner-container">
                        <h1>portfolio</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slide" id="about">
                    <div id="inner-container">
                        <p>about</p>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
                <div class="slide" id="contact">
                    <div id="inner-container">
                        <h1>Contact</h1>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
div#transition-slide-container {    
    background: #bee1ff;    
    padding-top: 128px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    height: 900px;
    width: 400%;    
    z-index: -1;
    position: relative;
}
div#transition-slide {
    white-space: nowrap;
    left: 0;
}
.slide {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    border-left: 1px #000 solid;
}
div#inner-container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Website: andrewgu12.kodingen.com
Edit: Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Gtaf/
Thanks!

Comment: Is there example in http://jsfiddle.net/ please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6Gtaf/ Here it is

Comment: So, what would you like to center? Content of inner container?

Comment: note: widths in percent are based on the parent container. Since the container is 400%, you want the  `.slide` widths to be 25%. Then just add `text-align:center` to the .slides, as per http://jsfiddle.net/6Gtaf/1/

Comment: @FSou1 Yes, I want to center the content inside `inner-container`. @Dom Day, would everything be centered if I added in more than just text(i.e. forms, images, etc)?

Comment: unless they are floated, or otherwise positionally modified, yes. http://jsfiddle.net/6Gtaf/2/

Comment: @DomDay, nor if they don't take the entire width of their container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9vjd/4/) *&* [full-screen preview](http://jsfiddle.net/d9vjd/4/embedded/result/)

You should either specify `min-width: 400%` instead of `width`, or set `max-width: 960px` on `.silde`.  Otherwise, 4 slides won't fit in smaller than a 960px wide viewport, e.g. every phone (try scrolling to the right on the @sourcecode's fiddle).

The `position: absolute` is pointless and not good, unless `.slide` is positioned relative, and coordinates are set, but there's no need to do that.

Also, borders are **in addition** to the size of the element.  You must either change the box model, via `box-sizing: border-box`, set your width to slightly less than 25%, or have 1px extra on the sides.

`text-align` center will *not** center block-level elements.  By default, they span 100% of the width of their parent, and the text inside them is centered.  In the demo, I created one div that's 30x30 pixels.  Another has the same style, but also `margin: 0 auto;`.

Setting the container to have a `min-height: 100%` allows it to grow as needed, doesn't force a scrollbar if it's not needed, and makes sure it takes up at least the entire screen vertically.

Comment: Thank you! Everything turned out perfectly ^^

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `text-align:center` to the **slide** class.

```
.slide {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    border-left: 1px #000 solid;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Here's an [updated version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shanosha/6Gtaf/5/).

Also, I noticed you repeat "inner-container" as an id in each slide. You probably should change that to a class since there are multiple instances of it in the same HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to center align text in `div-container` then use:

`text-align:center;` in your css , here is the demo :[jfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d9vjd/)

Comment: On my page here, http://andrewgu12.kodingen.com/#contact, I've been trying to center the form. How would I do that?

Comment: center the form means what..? as visible its horizontally centered, do you want it be vertically centered?

Comment: @Andrew, set a width on it.  Something like `width:50%` or `width:400px; max-width: 90%`.  And put `margin: 0 auto`.  Optionally replace the 0 with your desired top/bottom margin.